# Problems with IntelliJ and GWT Facets

Tags: gwt, intellij-idea

I'm trying to add the GWT facet to a module. I've done this for other modules before without problems, but am running into strange issues with this one. IntelliJ 12.1.3 Ultimate.

I select "Project Structure", and it takes several seconds for the screen to come up. The "Path to GWT installtion directory" is blank, but selecting the drop-down gives me the same (valid) directory four times.

Selecting one of them gives me the warning at the bottom "gwt-user.jar in library 'gwt-servlet.jar' does not correspond to selected GWT installation". Selecting the "Fix" button doesn't seem to do anything, and once I have pressed "Fix", neither the "OK" nor "Apply" button seem to do anything.

If, at this point, I hit "Cancel", selecting "Project Structure" doesn't seem to ever re-open the window.

Any pointers or suggestions about where to proceed in resolving the problem?

Comment: Try to invalidate the caches to see if it helps. `File -> Invalidate Caches...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After combing through error logs and trying to figure out what was up, I gave up on the problem. When I returned, I found that there were a number of problems that probably contributed to this error:

1. The module had a dependency on an older version of the gwt-user.jar. This was listed in `Modules -> Dependencies`, but it wasn't immediately clear that it didn't match the version in `Facets -> Path to GWT installation directory`
2. Several of the modules that were listed as dependencies of the core module also had the older version of gwt-user.jar.
3. Several of the modules that were listed as dependencies of the core module were given the GWT facet, but didn't have entry points or any need to compile the source into JS. They would just be compiled as part of the depending project. So they didn't need the GWT facet.

I don't know why these were causing problems inside IntelliJ IDEA itself, but they certainly weren't correct, and cleaning them up allowed the GWT components to compile.